# Magento 2.1 PHP version suggestion

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-7, php-5.6

I recently got a project in Magento 2.1 CE (from scratch). Although the officially recommended of PHP is 5.6, I am more inclined to go with PHP7.

I was looking for a Pros and Cons list of going with either of the PHP versions.

Any thoughts people ?

Comment: I suggest to you PHP7. PHP7 is much faster then other version and also Magento2 is stable working with PHP7.

Comment: as compared to php 5  , php7 is much faster with magento2.1. https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-php7-25-performance-increase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 7

- Pro: Much faster
- Con: Possible bugs

PHP 5.6

- Pro: More reliable
- Con: Slower

That's pretty much all it comes down to. At this point, PHP 7 is fairly stable, every module you find for M2 should support it out of box, so you're not likely to run into any problems.

I wouldn't build a site on anything less than PHP 7.

Comment: hey, @ryan Hoerr,  IS php7 best for magento-2.1.6?

Comment: PHP 7 is always better than PHP 5, unless your code isn't compatible. PHP 7 will actually be required for Magento 2.2 and above--they're dropping support for PHP 5 completely.

Comment: Yes, i have checked it for 2.2. it working on  supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later